# Change text of Unity 4.6 UI button

Tags: button, text, unity-game-engine

I've been trying for days without success. How do I change the text of a Unity 4.6 button using C# script? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a script and add it to your UIButton
you should add the reference Unity.UI

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

then declare a variable

```
Text yourButtonText;
```

on the function Start put this

```
void Start()
{
    yourButtonText = transform.FindChild("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
}
```

then when you want to change your text add this

```
yourButtonText.text = "i am a button!";
```

if you need to apply more modifications visit http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html

**[VERSION WITH TAGS]**

add this reference

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public Text[] yourButtonTextArrays = new Text[15];

void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++ )
    {
        yourButtonTextArrays[i] = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Button" + i+1.ToString()).transform.FindChild("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
    }
}
```

then when you want to change your text add this

```
yourButtonTextArrays[yourButtonNumber].text = "i am a button from the array of buttons";
```

Comment: There are 3 rows of 5 buttons in the Scene. Each button has a tag. I was hoping to somehow use the tags to find the button and then change the text.

Comment: how are the tags formatted? example Button0 Button1 etc?

Comment: Exactly. Button1 Button2 and so on.

Comment: Interesting. Tags that have the first letter the same are considered duplicates. Also, I get the error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Scramble.SetButtonsText () (at Assets/Scripts/Scramble.cs:56)
Scramble.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Scramble.cs:46) yourButtonTextArrays[yourButtonNumber].text = "A";

Comment: FIXED! Give a it a try now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67059/discussion-between-jadkins4-and-quakenxt).

Comment: Thank you for all the help. Using your tips, I created a simple C# script to change the text of a button. I used it as a guide to modify my more complex script with button arrays.

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ButtonTest : MonoBehaviour {
 public GameObject Button1;
 Text MyButtonText;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
  MyButtonText = Button1.transform.FindChild("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
  MyButtonText.text = "Hello there";
 }
}

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object . How to overcome this issue?