# Stop count when game over and store value

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-ui

For my new game in Unity3D, I created Javascript code that allows to count when the player is playing and display the value in a GUIText.

But I have some issues.

In the game, the count start and the GUIText shows the value of the count.
But when I come to the game over, the count doesn't stop.

In the quit scene, the GUIText that shows the value of the count of the game scene, restart from 0 and it don't stop.

Here is the script:

```
var Counter : int = 0;
var score : GUIText;

function Start () {

}

function Update () {

  Counter++;
  score.text = Counter.ToString();

}
```

So what I want to do is to stop the count when the game over comes, and store the value so in the next scene, the GUIText shows the final value.

How can I do that?

Comment: I did you unity3d 2 years ago, can't remeber methods.  maintain some kind of boolean variable to keep track of the game status and show score only when that variable set to true. So when you game over the status of the variable will change to false so that score board wil never show up. ie. `if(!gameover){//show score}` in your onGUI method

Comment: where did i place this line of code?

Comment: I guess there is a function called `onGuI` where you'll show your score. there you need to show score only when game is not over.. share your code so that I can help you

Comment: @Ophélia , DO NOT USE the "legacy" gui system. It does not work.  You are completely wasting your time.  The good news is it is super-easy to use the ordinary UI system.  (1) click "add UI canvas"  (2) click "add UI text".  you're done.  You can find a million tutorials, etc. it is VERY easy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change text of Unity 4.6 UI button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510743/change-text-of-unity-4-6-ui-button)

Comment: you can find any numer of tutorials eg http://stackoverflow.com/a/34744087/294884   https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui

Comment: i did this all ready but what i am trying to do is to stop the count and display the value in another GUIText

Comment: I recommend that you check the game's state to start counting by keeping two variables (IsStartGame, ISFinishGame).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
private var isFinished : boolean = false;

var Counter : int = 0;
var score : GUIText;

function Start () {

}

function Update () {

  if(!isFinished){
      Counter++;
      score.text = Counter.ToString();
  }

  if ("something that makes the game stop") {
       isFinished = true;
  }
}
```

Then to pass a variable into the next scene, you could use `PlayerPrefs` to store your variable, and then  retrieve it in the next scene, have a look [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.SetInt.html) and [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.GetInt.html)

Comment: hey thank you for you reply. i don't understand when the counter stop in the script? (i have error BCE0043 unexpected token : bool)

Comment: @Ophélia That appeared to have been a syntax error in the answer, used C# instead of UnityScript variable. Edited the answer to fix this.

Comment: @Serlite Sorry about that, I code in C# so it just came naturally! The code should work now!

Comment: thanks a lot! but i can i use PlayerPrefs? to store the value and show it in another scene.

Comment: yes i will do it, but the previous script not working... i still have the same problem and i don't know how to resolve them.

Answer (score 0):

You should need to restricted the  counter increment using a variable state in your game over event. (I don't know how your making your game end)

```
    var Counter : int = 0;
    var score : GUIText;
    var isGameOver = false; //true this variable as your gameover
    function Start () {

    }

    function Update () {
    //isGameOver variable to check that  the game is over or not
    if(!isGameOver){
      Counter++;
      score.text = Counter.ToString();
    }

    }
```